# 'str' object integer error for os.open in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm a fairly new programmer, and trying to do my first file read.

My aim is to strip unnecessary line breaks from text in a .txt file copied from a PDF, but I cannot get the file to open.

I already swapped the slash direction, as the \ for windows directories was interpreted as an exception character in the filename string

My question is:

Why does this code:

```
import os
my_file = os.open('C:/Users/USER/Documents/20 Programming/Code institute 5 day coding challenge.txt', 'r')
my_file.close()
```

give this error?

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Here is the full console output:

```
"C:\Users\USER\Documents\20 Programming\untitled\venv\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\USER\Documents\20 Programming\untitled\remove carriage returns if no capital letter next.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\20 Programming\untitled\remove carriage returns if no capital letter next.py", line 21, in <module>
    my_file = os.open('C:/Users/USER/Documents/20 Programming/Code institute 5 day coding challenge.txt', 'r')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I've tried googling the error and had no joy, as this error isn't discussed in relation to open() as far as I can find.

I'm expecting the file to open so I can read the results

Edit:
Thanks everyone. I've now replaced os.open() with just open(). I've now got a different error (file not found) so I'll try to tackle that next... (note this is not a new question!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you using `os.open()`, that is a function for *very* specialized needs.  The parameters you are passing only make sense for the ordinary `open()` function.

Comment: Do not import *os*. Just call *open()*

Comment: Why are you using `os.open()`?  Did you see that in some tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, I am not sure why you are using `open.os()`. As for the issue you are facing, you can simply use

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    # read the contents of the file and remove all line breaks
    contents = file.read().replace('\n', '')

# print the contents of the file without line breaks
print(contents)
```

The reason you are gettng the error is because `open.os()` expects an integer constant as the second argument where you are passing a string (`r`).The correct code would be something like

```
import os
my_file = os.open('C:/Users/USER/Documents/20 Programming/Code institute 5 day coding challenge.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
os.close(my_file)
```

example call
`os.open(file, flags[, mode]);`

`os.O_RDONLY` is the flag sayng open it for reading only it represents an integer value.
You can look up the docs for any function. For e.g https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm